# Integrate cli in vsCode terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For an extension that I am working on I would like to integrate a separate CMD window that is started by a different program in the terminal of vscode, the same way it is done currently in Emacs.
The way it currently works is that I can start the program from vsCode using the following code:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
//execCommand = "C:/.../.../gis.exe -a c:/.../.../alias start"
exec(execCommand, (err, stdout, stderr) => { 
if (err)
    return console.error(err);
else 
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

When this part of the code is run the program starts and then opens a separate CLI window. I would like this CLI window to be integrated in the native terminal of vscode.
Any way to "catch" the CLI window or redirect the output/input of the CLI window?

Answer (score 0):

Not long ago I build a a little script that did the same thing. While I cannot share my code, the approach I took was to make my code to **simulate** JS key press, which will trigger the key command for opening the terminal (**Ctr+`**) and it worked. Hope that helps.